# CollectionView is not scrolling without setting the height property

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, maui

In my .Net Maui project I'm using a CollectionView within a ControlTemplate. The implementation is looking like this:

```
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <SearchBar
                x:Name="ObjectSearchBar"
                Grid.Row="0"
                IsSpellCheckEnabled="False"
                Keyboard="Text"
                Placeholder="{TemplateBinding SearchBarPlaceholderText}"
                TextChanged="ObjectSearchBar_TextChanged" />

            <CollectionView
                x:Name="ObjectResultView"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="10,10,10,10"
                ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureAllItems"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
                ItemsLayout="VerticalList"
                ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding DataSource}"
                SelectionChanged="ObjectResultView_SelectionChanged"
                SelectionMode="Single">
            </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
<ContentView.ControlTemplate>
```

I'm using this ContentView within a ContentPage. The Page contains 2 StackLayouts and it's implementation is looking like this:

```
 <ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>
        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsVisible="{Binding AddNewSectionIsVisible, Converter {converter:InvertedBoolConverter}}"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <controls:ObjectSearchControl
                DataSource="{Binding DataSource}"
                FilterChangedCommand="{Binding FilterChangedCommand}"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                ObjectSelectedCommand="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
                SearchBarPlaceholderText="ABC"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            IsVisible="{Binding AddNewSectionIsVisible}"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Style="{StaticResource rootStackLayout}"
            VerticalOptions="Center">
            
            ....

        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Only one of the StackLayouts is displayed when the Page is Appearing.

So, if I set the height of the second row to a fixed value or set the height of the CollectionView to a fixed value scrolling is working fine. But if I use a "*" or "Auto" for the height definition of the second row the CollectionView isn't scrolling anymore.

Please, can someone help me in this case? I also tried using ScrollViews, setting the VerticalOptions of the Stacklayouts or the Grid to "FillAndExpand" like it's described in MS documentation but nothing seems to work for me.

Answer (score 9):

Had the same issue at 03.29.2023 with all the latest Maui libraries (8.0.0-preview.2).

What helped me to fix the scrolling is setting `VerticalOptions` to `FillAndExpand`

Option `Fill` does not work

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 3):

By refactoring the layout I found a solution for my problem.

I replaced all the `StackLayouts` through `Grids` and add a `ScrollView` in my control.
Seems the reason for my problem have been the complex layout.

Comment: Adding a scrollview in the grid was what fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I had a very similar issue with CollectionView not scrolling when it was preceded by a Grid and everything wrapped in a VerticalStackLayout. I just replaced the outer VerticalStackLayout with a Grid and the CollectionView scrolls just fine. I didn't need to add a ScrollView.

Answer (score 1):

I think layout logic failed to realize the collectionview should scroll.

---

**ATTEMPTED FIX #1**

Try these 2 changes:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <!-- 1) "*": make sure row 0 takes all vertical space. -->
    <Grid RowDefinitions="*">
    
        <!-- 2) remove the surrounding StackLayout, to simplify layout logic. -->
        <controls:ObjectSearchControl
            IsVisible="{Binding AddNewSectionIsVisible, Converter {converter:InvertedBoolConverter}}"
            DataSource="{Binding DataSource}"
            FilterChangedCommand="{Binding FilterChangedCommand}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            ObjectSelectedCommand="{Binding SelectedCommand}"
            SearchBarPlaceholderText="ABC"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

---

**TEST IF #1 DID NOT WORK**

If the above did not help, then please do this test:

```
<controls:ObjectSearchControl
     IsVisible="True"

... and set the other stacklayout to `IsVisible="False"`.
```

That is, as a test, force that control to be visible before `InitializeComponent` is called from the constructor. This should cause CollectionView to be properly marked as scrolling.

The results of this test are needed, to know what approach to take next.

---

**ATTEMPTED FIX #2 TBD**

If #1 did not help, then it is because when page is first laid out, the CollectionView was not marked as needing to scroll.

This can be caused either by the dynamic `IsVisible` property, or by layout occurring before `DataSource` had any contents.

Its a subtle bug in CollectionView, that has been seen in other circumstances.

TBD: Research earlier Q&As, to decide easiest way to fix.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! Unfortunately there is a bug in Maui Prev. 11 so I cann't try your suggestions. If the bug is fixed, I'll try and give you feedback!

Comment: @Phil - which bug is that? Just curious

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4015 and
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4011 and
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/4007

Seems there is a problem in Prev. 11 with rendering Grid-, List- or CollectionViews under Android

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It put me on the right track!!!

Comment: @Phil. Glad it helped. Remember to upvote answers that help you.